# Iterate gutenberg blocks class in render_callback generated from acf_register_block

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have here a function that adds a custom block in gutenberg

```
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
function my_acf_init() {

    if( function_exists('acf_register_block') ) {

        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'              => 'h2-block',
            'title'             => __('H2 Block'),
            'description'       => __('A custom H2 block.'),
            'render_callback'   => 'h2_block_render_callback',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
            'icon'              => 'admin-comments',
            'supports' => array(
                'align' => array( 'left', 'right' ),
            ),
        ));

    }
}
```

and here is the render callback

```
function h2_block_render_callback( $block ) {
    ?>
    <div class="section_one">
        <div class="intro_title">
        <?php echo '<h2><b>'.get_field('h2_content').'</b></h2>'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

so I would want to every time I add a custom blocks in Gutenberg the div class iterates like section_one, section_two, section_three or maybe section_1, section_2

I really don't know Gutenberg blocks yet, any help is very much appreciated :-)